# Reading file input with ruby via command line input

Tags: ruby, file

So I am trying to read a file in ruby by giving the name via the command line. So far my code reads as follows:

```
puts "What is the name of the file to read?"
fileName = gets.chomp

file = $stdin.read.strip
f = File.open(file, “r”)
f.each_line { |line|
    puts line
    }
```

What I see happening is it is reading the inputs through the command line but does not read a file. For example, I can pass 'input.txt', 'code.txt', and 'sonic.txt' as file names but the program just loops back seeking another input. How can I change this to read the file by name and then out put the contents of that file?

Comment: And removing file = $stdin.read.strip does not yield a quality result.

Comment: I can edit the question rather than add comments.

Comment: What is the line `fileName = gets.chomp` for? `fileName` is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems are:

- The line `fileName = gets.chomp` is useless. Remove that.
- `file = $stdin.read.strip` will not let you terminate the input. Use `gets` to get user's input from the command line.
- You are using the wrong quotation `“` in your parameter `“r”` for `File.open`.
- You are not closing the file after reading it. It is better to use the block form of `File.open` to ensure the file is closed after using.

Here is a minimum fix:

```
puts "What is the name of the file to read?"
file = gets.chomp
File.open(file, "r"){|f|
  f.each_line {|line|
    puts line
  }
}
```